# Rename all downloaded files to their comment

Tags: download, download-manager

FlashGet Download Manager has a 'Use Comment' feature for renaming the downloaded file to its comment text.
But is there any solution for renaming all downloaded files to their comment text at the same time in FlashGet or other download manager?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?